# Can't set file with "echo" from a program via system()

Tags: c, linux, system

I'm try to use system("echo 1 > /sys/class/afile") to set a file to 1.

If I use it on console it works well, but if I run my C program it shows me:

```
sh: echo: I/O error
```

I already try to set it with following code:

```
char i[1];
i[0]=1;
int fd1 = open("/sys/class/afile",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
int ret = write(fd1,i,strlen(i));
if(ret > 0)
   printf("Ok\n");
else
   printf("nOk\n");
close(fd1);
```

The result is "Ok" but the file didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strlen(i)` yields undefined behavior because `i` is not a string; the array lacks room for null termination. Also, `i[0]=1;` does not put a `'1'` character in the array, but rather puts a byte with value 1, which is a "`^A` character".

Instead try `write(fd, "1", 1)` - no need for any variables or `strlen`.

Comment: Also note that you need to pass an ASCII "1"=0x31 to that file, not a binary 0x01.

Comment: That's what I just said.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
int fd1 = open("/sys/class/afile",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
```

you need to provide **mode** in the third argument of `open()` since you are using `O_CREAT`.

From the manual page of [open](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)

> int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);

It says

> **O_CREAT**
>
> If pathname does not exist, create it as a regular file.
>
> The **mode** argument specifies the **file mode bits** be applied when
>   a new file is created.  **This argument must be supplied when
>   **O_CREAT** or O_TMPFILE is specified in flags;**

For e.g you can try this

```
int fd1 = open("/sys/class/afile",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0664);
```

And do check return value of `open()` system call with `perror()`.

Also here

```
char i[1];
int ret = write(fd1,i,strlen(i));
```

as @R pointed, `strlen(i)` causes **undefined behavior** since `i` is declared of `1` byte & there is no space for `\0` char to null terminate the char buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your program, first I wasn't able to write file without sudo persmission:

```
~/Documents/src/progs : $ echo 1 > /sys/class/afile
bash: /sys/class/afile: Permission denied
```

If you try to do the same thing with some file in local directory(not in root folders), you should be able to write your file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  FILE* pFile = fopen("afile", "w");
  fprintf(pFile, "1\n");

  fclose(pFile);
}
```